# Android Studio's Virtual Device Manager cannot access localhost with port

Tags: angular, android-virtual-device

Im running an Angular application on the default local server with `ng serve`. Now trying to access the page from the AVD Manager with `10.0.2.2:4200` doesnt work. Im getting

> 10.0.2.2 refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The internet connection is working.
Im using Chrome on Android 12 and running it on a macbook m1

What am I doing wrong?